# Tag synonym/merge eclipse-plugin and eclipse-plugin-dev

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Sadly, I do not have the needed reputation to do this the proper way. For those who do, please consider making [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) a synonym for [eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin) or merge these.